# Circleci, SequelizeConnectionError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, circleci

I am using circleci to run some tests involving the database. My server uses node and sequelize as the orm. Whenever, I run my tests I get the following error:

```
SequelizeConnectionError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host X, user X, database X, SSL off
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my model index file, where I create the instance of Sequelize, I needed to add the following options:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  database_url,
  {
    ssl = true,
    dialectOptions = {
      ssl: true,
    },
  },
);
```

This fixed the it. The key is to set both ssl options. The problem was Sequelize was not using ssl.